# How do I search forms in Access using values from another table that is being referenced?

Tags: forms, ms-access, search

The management staff in my department has been asked to record any and all errors committed by our team. I created a database to store them and a simple form for the management team to use to record each error. Several fields are referencing other tables such as Staff, issue category, root cause, etc...
We need to be able to search the forms for specific records to either update or review, and I have found the best way for us to search is by filtering the forms based on the individual who committed the error. Here is the code that I am using for the search button:

Private Sub SearchRecord_Click()
Dim Search As String
Search = InputBox("Please enter who committed the error", "Name", ErrorMadeBy)
If Search = "" Then Exit Sub
Me.Filter = "ErrorMadeBy = """*" & Search & "*""
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub

The filter works great, but instead of filling out the name, you have to use the ID number in the Staff table when filling out the Input Box. I'd like to be able to input the name (or part of the name) instead of having to have everyone memorize the ID numbers from the staff table.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in these cases?

Fire up the query builder - left join in those extra tables (with the text parts in place of the id).

So be it a part number, quote number for a project etc? Just left join in those tables in the query builder and save that query.

Now, your search box and code can be somthing like:

```
dim rst       as DAO.RecordSet
strSQL = "Select * from MyCoolQuery where PartName like '" & txtPartName & "*'"
set rst = currentdb.OpenRecordSet(strSQL)
if rst.EOF = false then
   me.RecordSet.FindFirst "PartID = " & rst!PartID
end if
```

In fact, you can even often left join in those extra tables right into the current form, and even use ctrl-f to search if the said text boxes are place on the given form. However, I tend to separate out the search process from the actual form. So I might build a search form, say like this:

[image]

So in above, they can search say by a Hotel name, or project name or whatever. Becuase the one query has the text parts, then they can be searched. But I put the query results into a grid and each row of course has the PK ID, and thus a search could result in 10 matches, they are now free to click on any row - and i jump to the form to display the one records.

eg: the row click button does this:

```
docmd.OpenForm "frmTourBooking",,,"ID = " & me!ID
```

So, this makes for a great work flow. Users search, see, pick and then jump to the form with the one record, and then close and return back to search form - and often it has the several "hits" from that search that you want to work on anyway.